# QGIS3 Shape Digitizing Circles is Drawing Improperly

Tags: shapefile, circle, qgis-3, drawing

I'm trying to draw a circle in QGIS 3 with the shape digitizing toolbar. I've tried several of the "add circle" options and they all look normal while drawing, but once I click to finish the shape it is no longer a circle. Please see the attached photo. Any ideas on how to fix this so I can create circles?

[image: Red Circle is my "drawing"]

[image: Resulting shape]

Answer (score 8):

You are drawing a circle in the coordinate system of the layer. Qgis reproject that circle to the coordinate system of the project, and that figure probably no longer looks like a circle.

You need to set the coordinate system of the layer to EPSG:3721 before drawing the circle, if you want to see it like a circle in the project CRS (EPSG:3721).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your situation.
1. Created shape file in epsg:3721
2. Checked the same epsg for the project
3. Draw a circle at the same place

Here is the result
[image: Circle]

Comment: Yeah that is what its supposed to do and what its always done before....

Answer (score 0):

Update your layer coordinate reference system to match your project's.

You can do that by:

1. *Toggle editing* on the layer
2. Right click on the layer name and select *Properties*
3. Select *Source*
4. Under *Geometry and Coordinate Reference System* click on the select button and find the one that matchs your project (It's listed with the *Project CRS* prefix)