# QGIS 'Add Circle' Feature not working correctly?

Tags: qgis

I'm new to QGIS. Recently, I had my first experience of having to draw a circle. This is in a Geopackage layer using the 'Add Circle' option from the Edit menu, only whenever I go to draw it, it ends up...not circular.

Circle preview:
[image]
Circle drawn:
[image]
Somebody else had a similar problem, see here: [QGIS3 Shape Digitizing Circles is Drawing Improperly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306140/qgis3-shape-digitizing-circles-is-drawing-improperly) . Setting my coordinates to EPSG:3721 does allow me to draw a proper circle, but when I switch back to EPSG:32230 it's an oval (and I'm not sure how well EPSQ:3271 works for local-scale mapping in Scotland...). Is there any way around this that doesn't involve changing projections?

Comment: Sorry, your question is extremely confusing - once you tell us you use EPSG:3721, then its 3271 - both are not valid in Scotland...

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem has been described here as the bug:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38493

and here:

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/25167

I had the same problem as you. I had roughly the same shape when using EPSG:4326.

You cannot do it without changing the geometry, but you can reproject your circle afterward to the geometry you want to use in your project.

[image]

Change your CRS system to EPSG:3857. You should get the proper circle.
Then export it (reproject) where you will select the initial CRS system you are working on.

[image]

Alternatively, you can take a look at this plugin:

[Shape tools](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/shapetools/)